# How to fix org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException exception in spring boot application

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I am getting the below exception when i run the spring boot application.
But the same code works fine when we execute as a plain java.

Exception:

> at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
>       Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of com.sample.model.TRSN_LOOKUP.emClntId
>           at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterMethodImpl.get(GetterMethodImpl.java:64)
>           at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:230)
>           at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4725)

This is for spring-boot standalone application running in windows

```
 Session session = getSession();
if (!session.getTransaction().isActive() )
    session.beginTransaction();

    TRSN_LOOKUP trsnlookup = new TRSN_LOOKUP();             

        trsnlookup.setPrsnid(PrsnId);
        trsnlookup.setEmClntId(clientId);           

    session.save(trsnlookup);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: Just check your DB properties which makes the connection. I suspect over there. or else post your DB connection properties.

Comment: <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
       <property name="hibernate.default_schema">SC</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</property> 
        <property name="cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider</property>

Answer (score 0):

Continuation from my above comments:

Just try with `naming-strategy` property which will help you to use a similar name.

*For example,:* Spring will change entity name from `TRSN_LOOKUP` to `tRSN_LOOKUP`. So, please try adding one more property in hibernate.

There are two types of strategy, you can use 2nd one:

`1. org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy`

`2. org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl`

which help you keep the same name in all DB fields.